# redirecting pages using session

Tags: asp.net

i'm new to ASP.NET,so plz b patient :D
i want to redirect one of my pages to the other one,and i keep the username!
i tried to use session.add and session[],but when i want to insert the username inside the brackets,it says use must int!!!but i thought i should use session["username"]
i used another way(request.querystring[]),but both have problems
here is my code

```
    //first solution    
    string username="asal";
    session.Add(username,username);  
    Response.Redirect("~/Doctor/DoctorsMainPage.aspx");
    //in the other page  
    Label1.Text= Session["username"].ToString();//this one says use int?!
    //i used this one instead of it
    Label1.Text= Session[0].ToString();//with this one i get the username in other page,but one i want to pass another string like "id" with session,I can not!

    //the second solution  
    string username="asal";
    Response.Redirect("~/Doctor/DoctorsMainPage.aspx?username");
    Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["username"];//this one redirect to doctors main page but set the value of username to "" !
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the session like..

`session.Add("username",username);` instead `session.Add(username,username);`

And then you can access the value like..`Label1.Text= (String)Session["username"];`

Check out this article related to the session State [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx#Y751) that will help you to understand Session State management.

Seconly querystring should be like, as you have not passing your string parameter and it should be like...

```
 Response.Redirect("~/Doctor/DoctorsMainPage.aspx?username=" + username);
```

Answer (score 0):

session.Add(string, string) where the first string is the name of the variable and the second is the value.

You are adding the value twice.

```
//first solution    
string username="asal";
session.Add("username",username);  <-- this is your problem
Response.Redirect("~/Doctor/DoctorsMainPage.aspx");

//in the other page  
Label1.Text= Session["username"].ToString();
```

Now, as for

```
//the second solution  
string username="asal";
Response.Redirect("~/Doctor/DoctorsMainPage.aspx?username");
Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["username"];//this one redirect to doctors main page but set the value of username to "" !
```

In this case you're creating a url "~/Doctor/DoctorsMainPage.aspx?username"

Ok - so what is username?  The code is looking for a param in the query string named username but it's not finding a value.
You need:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Doctor/DoctorsMainPage.aspx?username="+username);
```

That will give you "~/Doctor/DoctorsMainPage.aspx?username=asal"

Answer (score 0):

```
 string username = "asal";
        Session["username"] = username;  
        Response.Redirect("~/Doctor/DoctorsMainPage.aspx");

        //Other page
        Label1.Text = Session["username"].ToString().Trim();
```